# Qt: Run a script BEFORE make

Tags: qt, makefile

I have a script, runScript.sh, that I would like to have run (to setup some environment variables and such) BEFORE making the application.

Using advice from [Running a program/script from QMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612283/running-a-program-script-from-qmake), in my .pro file, I have on the first line,

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += ./runScript.sh
```

which will, on a `make`, compile and link my application and THEN run the script.

I've seen examples of [how to set the script up as a target](http://dev.modmancer.com/index.php/2010/11/14/qmake-building-dependencies/)  in the .pro file,but I am not sure if I quite grasp the concept. Could someone explain it better or (even better) does anyone know how to do what I'm trying to do simpler (I was hoping for a "QMAKE_PRE_LINK" but that does not seem to exist lol)?

Using Qt-4.8.4 & qmake 2.03

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Link you've posted explains that very well.

```
extralib.target = extra
extralib.commands = echo "Building extralib.."; \    # Run your programs here
                make -w -C ../my_libraries/extralib; \
                echo "Done building extralib."; \

extralib.depends =
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += extralib
PRE_TARGETDEPS = extra
```

So, that could just be rewritten as

```
    extralib.target = extra
    extralib.commands = echo "Setuping the envirovment.."; \
                            export MYVAR="/usr/src/whatever" \
                            export SECONDVAR="/home/user" \
                            ./runScript.sh

    extralib.depends =



    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += extralib
    PRE_TARGETDEPS = extra
```

Comment: So, `extra` is the target - Aha! like declaring something as `.PHONY` in a makefile? What is `extralib` then - is it like an environment variable?

Comment: Ultimately, could I rename `extralib` or is that a reserved keyword?

Comment: I don't have compiler by myself here, but AFAIK, it is not a reserved keyword, so you could add just more than one in `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += extralib anotherextralib` and so on...